# maven fetching dependency from incorrect location

Tags: java, maven, github

Using [this tutorial](http://kwebble.com/blog/2014/02/19/use-github-to-host-your-own-maven-repo), I am trying to host a dependency on GitHub and then use the dependency in a separate application.

The dependency is located at:

https://github.com/user/repo/raw/master/release/tld/company/app/1.0.0/app-1.0.0.jar

However. maven keeps going to:

https://github.com/user/repo/raw/master/release/tld/company/app/app/1.0.0/app-1.0.0.pom

In my pom where I'm calling the dependency, I have:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>tld.company</id>
        <name>app</name>
        <url>https://github.com/user/repo/raw/master/release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>tld.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In **/master/company/release/tld/company/app/maven-metadata-local.xml** I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>tld.company.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>1.0.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20160233354414</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

In **/master/company/release/tld/company/app/1.0.0/app-1.0.0.pom** I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tld.company.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

What is the reason for the additional `/app` in the dependency download URL?

Comment: Your groupId is tld.company.app, your artifact is called app, so that makes tld/company/app/app. Why should it ignore one app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group id should be `tld.company`, not `tld.company.app`. This explains your second `app`.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>tld.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Basically, when you have a URL from a repository of the following form, this is how it is understood by Maven:

```
https://someserver.com/.../tld/company/app/1.0.0/app-1.0.0.jar
                           ^---------^ ^-^ ^---^ ^-----------^
                              groupId   | version   file name
                                     artifactId
```

- The last part if the file name which is `${artifactId}-${version}`.
- Before that is the version.
- Before that is the artifact id.
- And all the path before that are the group id, where slashes are replaced by dots.